# How is nvarchar(n) stored in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, storage

Does it occupy fixed `N*2` or it may use less storage if the actual value to be stored is smaller then `N*2` bytes?

I have a huge table with many fields of fixed `nvarchar` type. Some are `nvarchar(100)` and some are `nvarchar(400)` etc.

Data in column is never an exact size, it varies from `0` to `N`. Most of data is less then `N/2`.

For example, a field called `RecipientName` is of type `nvarchar(400)` and there are 9026424 rows.

Size of only `RecipientName` would be `800*9026424 = 6.72 GB`.

but actual storage size of entire table is only `2.02 GB`. Is there any compression applied or some smaller then N with power of 2 is chosen?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql

Comment: That *Unicode*, UTF16 specifically. It uses at least two bytes per character. It's *variable length* though, so the fields don't take 200 or 800 bytes, only what's needed. The fixed length types are `nchar` and `char` for ANSI

Comment: It takes space as it is used, if you have 10 characters in first row it will take 10 X 2 = 20 bytes. Hence you might end up less. Also check whether you have columnstore index set on that table

Comment: As for compression, you have to enable it explicitly for each table. You can use compression in all editions, from Express and Local DB up to Enterprise with SQL Server 2016 SP1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NCHAR data type:**

1. It is a **fixed** length data type.
2. It Occupies **2 bytes** of space for **EACH CHARACTER**.
3. It is used to store Unicode characters (e.g. other languages like Spanish, French, Arabic, German, etc.)

For Example:

```
Declare @Name NChar(20);
Set @Name = N'Sachin'
Select @Name As Name, DATALENGTH(@Name) As [Datalength In Bytes], LEN(@Name) As [Length];


Name    Datalength  Length
Sachin  40          6
```

1. Even though declared size is 20, the data length column shows 40 bytes storage memory size because it uses 2 bytes for each character.
2. And this 40 bytes of memory is irrespective of the actual length of data stored.

**NVARCHAR data type:**

1. It is a **variable** length data type.
2. It Occupies **2 bytes** of space for **EACH CHARACTER**.
3. It is used to store Unicode characters (e.g. other languages like Spanish, French, Arabic, German, etc.)

For Example:

```
Declare @Name NVarchar(20);
Set @Name = N'Sachin'
Select @Name As Name, DATALENGTH(@Name) As [Datalength], LEN(@Name) As [Length];


Name    Datalength  Length
Sachin  12          6
```

1. Even though declared size is 20, the data length column shows 12 bytes storage memory size because it uses 2 bytes for each character.
2. And this 12 bytes of memory is irrespective of the length of data in the declaration.

Comment: It's actually a **minimum** of 2 bytes per character. Many Unicode characters from outside of the English alphabet take more than 2 bytes. See the Remarks section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

> it may use less storage if the actual value to be stored is smaller
>   then N*2 bytes

n just shows the maximum number of characters that can be stored in this field, the number of stored characters is equal to actual characters number you pass in.

And here is the documentation: [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

For non-`MAX`, non-`XML` string types, the length that they are declared as (i.e. the value within the parenthesis) is the maximum number of smallest (in terms of bytes) characters that will be allowed. But, the *actual* limit isn't calculated in terms of characters but in terms of bytes. `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` characters can be 1 or 2 bytes, so the smallest is 1 and hence a `[VAR]CHAR(100)` has a limit of 100 bytes. That 100 bytes can be filled up by 100 single-byte characters, or 50 double-byte characters, or any combination that does not exceed 100 bytes. `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` (stored as UTF-16 Little Endian) characters can be either 2 or 4 bytes, so the smallest is 2 and hence a `N[VAR]CHAR(100)` has a limit of 200 bytes. That 200 bytes can be filled up by 100 two-byte characters or 50 four-byte characters, or any combination that does not exceed 200 bytes.

If you enable ROW or DATA Compression (this is a per-*Index* setting), then the actual space used will usually be less. `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` use the Unicode Compression Algorithm which is somewhat complex so not easy to calculate what it would be. And I believe that the `MAX` types don't allow for compression.

Outside of those technicalities, the difference between the `VAR` and non-`VAR` types is simply that the `VAR` types take up only the space of each individual value inserted or updated, while the non-`VAR` types are blank-padded and always take up the declared amount of space (which is why one almost always uses the `VAR` types). The `MAX` types are only variable (i.e. there is no `CHAR(MAX)` or `NCHAR(MAX)`).